# Different sets of target frameworks in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

I have two C# console applications.  In one project, under Properties -> Application -> Target Framework, I can choose .NET Core 1.0 through .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5.0.  In a different project, I have none of those choices.  Instead I have .NET Framework 2.0 through .NET Framework 4.7.2.  (In addition, the csproj files of the two projects look very different.)  If I wanted to change one project to a framework only listed for the other, is that possible?

Comment: Please have a look at [Overview of porting from .NET Framework to .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting) and [Example of migrating to the latest .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modernize-desktop/example-migration)

Answer (score 1):

This page showed that .NET Core is a cross-platform, open-source successor to .NET Framework.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/introduction#net-core-and-net-5

If you want to change .NET Core project to .NET Framework project, you can refer to this page.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/architecture/modernize-desktop/example-migration

By the way, VS2022 can modify the target framework directly in the properties.

[image]

You can also refer to this.
[How to change .NET version in Visual Studio 2019 to .NET Framework 4.7.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68548433/how-to-change-net-version-in-visual-studio-2019-to-net-framework-4-7-2)